# MySQL - JSON_EXTRACT gives "invalid JSON path expression" error when attempting to manipulate JSON_LENGTH value

Tags: mysql, json

I have JSON column in my table called Source_Data where the structure is as follows:

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "submissions": [
        {
            "requestDateTime": 123,
            "request": {},
            "response": {
                "result": "ACCEPTED",
                "submissionId": "ABC"
            }
        },
        {
            "requestDateTime": 456,
            "request": {},
            "response": {
                "result": "REJECTED",
                "submissionId": "XYZ"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to read the last element in the `submissions` array, and the value of `result` within the `response` object. Therefore the desired output would be "REJECTED".

If I try the following, MySQL does **not** throw an error:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(Source_Data, CONCAT('$.submissions[', JSON_LENGTH(Source_Data ->> '$.submissions'), '].response.result')) AS Submission_Response
FROM test;
```

This is obviously wrong however, because arrays count from 0, so I need to do `JSON_LENGTH(Source_Data ->> "$.submissions") - 1` but this does not work, and the following error is shown:

> Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 14.

As soon as I add in the `- 1`, the query breaks, essentially.

Therefore, the offending query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(Source_Data, CONCAT('$.submissions[', JSON_LENGTH(Source_Data ->> '$.submissions') - 1, '].response.result')) AS Submission_Response
FROM test;
```

Any help on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated, thank you. I am using MySQL version 5.7.25 so cannot make use of 'last' (which I would love).

Comment: Select only the builded path and look at it.

Comment: @Akina I have tried that - `SELECT CONCAT("$.submissions[", JSON_LENGTH(Source_Data ->> "$.submissions") - 1, "].response.result") FROM test;` returns `$.submissions[1].response.result`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/fWvsY22q

Comment: @Akina thank you for sharing that, I've tried to run the last query but it just gives me the same error I described in the question - https://imgur.com/AxoCiHi

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the reason for this error. I had another record in the table whose `submissions` array was empty. Therefore the calculation to retrieve the entry in the array would give `-1` and MySQL takes issue with the dash in the JSON path.

Therefore, I amended the query as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(Source_Data, 
        CONCAT(
            '$.submissions[',
            GREATEST(JSON_LENGTH(Source_Data ->> '$.submissions') - 1, 0), 
            '].response.result'
        )
    ) AS Submission_Response
FROM test;
```